# correlation plot of high dimensional data looks unreadable

Tags: r, plot, r-corrplot

I am trying to do a correlation plot using corrplot in R with a high dimensional data consist of more than 100 variables. But the plot is unreadable as the `r` values in the cells are jumbled as it cannot accommodate the large (`121 * 121`) matrix in the plot. How can I make a bigger size plot so that the numbers are readable. This the command I used `corrplot(c, method="number", tl.cex = 0.6)`. [image: correlation plot using corrplot in R].

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you cannot expect the numbers to be visible. There simply is  not enough pixels on your screen to display the text.

What I would try is saving the graph in a pdf file:

```
pdf("file.pdf", height=45, width=45)
corrplot(c, method="number", tl.cex = 0.6)
dev.off()
```

Then open "file.pdf":

[image: img1]

And zoom in to see the numbers:

[image: img2]